# Create Subtotal Rows from Group but Remove the detail rows via TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, subtotal

I basically have:

```
select a,b,c,d,e from table1
```

I need the `subtotal` of e where c and d are the same. I suppose we can do a group by c and d but will run into a

> "..not part of aggregate function"

issue for columns `a` and `b` are not in an aggregate function or part of the group by clause.

Another thing, I only need a row with the subtotal result and not the rows that made up the subtotal

Comment: when you group c,d what a,b will do they will not group if they are different..
If you need group by c,d then remove a,b from select statement

Comment: can you share sample data and expected output?

Comment: @koushik column a and b will most likely be the same. I also need a and b in to the subtotal row so I can't remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c=d THEN e ELSE 0 END) as subTotal
FROM tableName
```

Comment: hi mmhasann, thanks for the response but I need to include columns a and b, which most likely are always the same through out rows